# The best way to do Vertical text for CJK characters?

Tags: css, html, cjk

As you may know, in mainland China, Taiwan, Japan and Korean, people sometimes writing and reading in vertical directions, [here's a simple example](http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/05/canvas-text-and-cjk.html):

Years ago, there're no way to do so.

Well, at least no beautiful methods, you know at that time one of the popular ways is: one div for each character.

Since organizations like W3 truely made some effort these years, I'm wondering is there any better way to do so.

I've found some attributes about text-directions in the standard docs, but I really wants to know about the IN FACT things like compatibility and so on.

I'd like to accept answers with using some experiment or developing standard like HTML5 and CSS3

any advice will be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check out the CSS3 `writing-mode` property. You'll find some useful infos at this URL (exemples, browsers compatibility,...):

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css